# Como atualizar o valor de uma variável dentro de um callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Estou criando um módulo com NodeJS e nesse módulo eu criei uma função que retorna um valor, sendo este valor atualizado dentro de uma função do tipo callback. O problema é que esta variável/valor não está sendo atualizado. Gostaria de saber como resolver o problema. Sou iniciante em NodeJS e pesquisei a respeito, mas não encontrei a solução para o meu problema. Segue abaixo o código, a variável a qual me refiro é a "output", declarada no inicio da função:

```
exports.sendMessage = function (chat, message, workspaceId){

    let output = "";

    chat.message(
        {
            input: { text: message },
            workspace_id: workspaceId
        },
        function (error, response){
            if(error){
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                output = response;
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
            }
        }
    );

    return output;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não dá pra usar retornos pra isso. Quando a função  `sendMessage` retorna, a função que você associou ao `chat.message` pode nem ter rodado ainda, porque tudo isso é assíncrono.

Lá onde você fez `output = response`, você deveria retirar isso e fazer uma chamada de função que vai continuar o trabalho pra você, pois só ali é que você tem certeza de que tem o valor de `response` correto.

Por exemplo:

```
processSendMessageResponse = function(response) {
    // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta.
}

exports.sendMessage = function (chat, message, workspaceId){

    let output = "";

    chat.message(
        {
            input: { text: message },
            workspace_id: workspaceId
        },
        function (error, response, output){
            if(error){
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                processSendMessageResponse(response)
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
            }
        }
    );

}
```

Outra opção é a função `sendMessage` receber por parâmetro, junto com os três que ela já recebe, a própria função que será chamada quando terminar. Por exemplo:

```
exports.sendMessage = function (chat, message, workspaceId, messageSentCallback){

    let output = "";

    chat.message(
        {
            input: { text: message },
            workspace_id: workspaceId
        },
        function (error, response, output){
            if(error){
                console.error(error);
            } else {
                messageSentCallback(response);
                console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
            }
        }
    );

}
```

e o uso dela poderia ser assim:

```
processSendMessageResponse = function(response) {
    // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta.
}

sendMessage(chat, message, workspaceId, processSendMessageResponse);
```

ou, mais simples ainda:

```
sendMessage(chat, message, workspaceId, function(response) {
    // fazer alguma coisa com a resposta.
});
```

Recomendo você ler mais sobre funções assíncronas para entender direito o paradigma, pois é essencial para trabalhar bem com NodeJS e Javascript em geral.

Comment: entendi o que você quis dizer. Mas teria alguma forma de eu conseguir retornar essa saída pra outro lugar? pois estou usando a função sendMessage em um outro arquivo/script, lá eu só faço a chamada da função e espero o retorno pra processar a resposta. Se eu processar a resposta com uma outra função como você fez no 'else' do callback, há uma forma de retornar essa resposta pra esse outro arquivo que estou usando? Agradeço desde já pela paciência.

Comment: Você vai precisar de uma função lá no outro arquivo que seja visível a partir dessa, semelhante ao que eu fiz na resposta, mas lá no outro arquivo. Ou você pode fazer a função `sendMessage` receber como parâmetro a própria função a ser chamada. Eu editei a resposta com essa solução.

Comment: Entendi. Vou tentar fazer isso e ver se resolve o meu problema. Muito obrigado por responder e pela paciência. Sou um completo iniciante em Node e preciso fazer um projeto utilizando essa ferramenta. Acabei aprendendo bastante coisa com sua resposta. Muito Obrigado, marcarei ela como correta!